# Differential equation of second order and first degree

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the differential equation of the equation: $$xy=Ae^x+Be^{-x}+x^2$$

I have tried like this:
$$xy=Ae^x+Be^{-x}+x^2\\
\implies xye^x=Ae^{2x}+B+e^xx^2\\
\implies e^xx\frac{dy}{dx}+y(e^x+xe^x)=2Ae^{2x}+e^xx^2+2xe^x\\
\implies x\frac{dy}{dx}+y+xy=2Ae^x+x^2+2x\\
\implies xe^{-x}\frac{dy}{dx}+y(e^{-x}+xe^{-x})=2A+e^{-x}x^2+2xe^{-x}\\
\implies xe^{-x}\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{dy}{dx}(e^{-x}-xe^{-x})+\frac{dy}{dx}(e^{-x}+xe^{-x})+y(-e^{-x}+e^{-x}-xe^{-x})=2xe^{-x}-e^{-x}x^2+2e^{-x}-2xe^{-x}\\
\implies x\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{dy}{dx}(1-x)+\frac{dy}{dx}(1+x)-xy=2-x^2\\
\implies x\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+2\frac{dy}{dx}-xy+x^2-2=0$$

I have tried it but there is two characters $~(x^2-2)~$ which is not in the answer.
 I cannot find my fault.
Please check this out.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Please recommend me a keyboard by which I can type the equation clearly

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange. Write your questions clearly. Please use MathJax . See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I make your equation in proper format. But I have a doubt about  the term $~xy~$, Is it $~xy~$ or it is $~y~$ ?

Comment: It is xy,and thank you for editing my question 

Comment: No though my equation has no derivatives, but the solution equation has derivatives

Comment: Okay, then see the answer posted by me @Ankita Pal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$xy=Ae^x+Be^{-x}+x^2\tag1$$
Differentiating both side with respect to $~x~$,
$$y+xy'=Ae^x-Be^{-x}+2x$$
Again differentiating both side with respect to $~x~$,
$$y'+y'+xy''=Ae^x+Be^{-x}+2$$
$$\implies xy''+2y'=xy-x^2+2\qquad \text{(using $(1)$)}$$
$$\implies  xy''+2y'-xy=2-x^2$$
This is the required differential equation.

Comment: This solution is more understandable 

Answer (score 0):

Calling

$$
f(x,y(x)) = xy-Ae^x-Be^{-x}-x^2=0
$$

we have

$$
\cases{f'(x,y(x)) = -A e^x+B e^{-x}+x y'(x)+y(x)-2 x=0\\
f''(x,y(x)) = -A e^x-B e^{-x}+x y''(x)+2 y'(x)-2=0
}
$$

solving for $A,B$ we get

$$
\cases{A= \frac{1}{2} e^{-x} \left(x y''(x)+x y'(x)+2 y'(x)+y(x)-2 x-2\right)\\
B= -\frac{1}{2} e^x \left(-x
   y''(x)+x y'(x)-2 y'(x)+y(x)-2 x+2\right)
}
$$

substituting those constants back into $f(x,y(x))$ we get

$$
x y''(x)+2 y'(x)-x y(x)-2+x^2=0
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$xy=Ae^x+Be^{-x}+x^2$$
Substitute $v=xy$
$$v=Ae^x+Be^{-x}+x^2$$
The polynomial characteristic is
$$(r-1)(r+1)=0 \implies r^2-1=0$$
Therefore the homogeneous equation is
$$v''-v=0 \implies (xy)''-xy=0$$
$$xy''+2y'-xy=0$$
Now treat the inhomogeneous equation where the particular solution is
$$y_p=x$$
$$xy''+2y'-xy=f(x)$$
$$f(x)=xy''+2y'-xy=0+2-x^2$$
Therefore the equation is:
$$xy''+2y'-xy=2-x^2$$